# JavaScript changing value of custom attribute by searching another custom attribute

Tags: javascript

thanks for reading.
So the input tags don't have an ID or a class name.
The value attribute is also custom. 
This is what I was trying.

HTML

```
<input name="password" data-value="">
```

.

```
@"var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var searchText = 'password';var found;  
  for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++)
  {
    if (aTags[i].textContent == searchText){found = 
       aTags[i].setAttribute('data-value','123456789');  
       alert(found.getAttribute('data-value')); break;}
  }");
```

or

```
var myInput=$('input[data-value='']').setAttribute('data-value','12345678'); 
alert(myInput.getAttribute('data-value'));
```

I tried using get elements by name, but there is nothing showing. As I think there may be multiple results. And I want a safer solution.

Comment: HTML isn't showing //<input name="password" data-value="" >

Comment: what is that `@"var` stuff

Comment: Could you provide an example inside a snippet ?

Comment: Do you want to set attribute to each input that value equals `searchText` or only to the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well thanks everyone, I didn't expect such a great response.

I was interested to see how this would be solved, but apparently the following line works

```
aTags[i].value='123456789';
```

I suppose anything with the word value is seen as a value field if the exact 'value' attribute can't be found.

Thanks flash, attr might work for this also I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myInput = $('input[name="password"]').setAttribute('data-value','12345678'); 
alert(myInput.getAttribute('data-value'));
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery already you can use the `attr()` method to get the value of the specified attribute.

```js
var myInput = $('input[data-value]').attr("data-value","12345678");
console.log(myInput.attr('data-value'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myInput = $('input[name="password"]').attr('data-value','12345678'); 
alert(myInput.attr('data-value'));
```

Try something like this

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help.

```js
const setAttribute = (attr, val) => input => {
  return input.setAttribute(attr, val)
}

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const searchValue = "1231"
  const selector = `input[value='${searchValue}']`;
  
  const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
  
  inputs.map(setAttribute("data-value", "1231231"))
  })
```

```html
<input value="1231" />
<input value="1231" />
<input value="aaa" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input />` is a self closed element so it will not have `textContent` attribute. But, yes, in some browsers it will work if you type `<input>text content</input>`, but in others it won't work.

What i recommend is to keep that value in an attribute right on the `input`. Follow the example bellow.

**Documentation:**

About textContent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Self Closing elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element

```
<input type="text" data-textcontent="password"/>
```

**JS**

```
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var found;
var searchText = 'password';var found;  
for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++)
{
  console.log(aTags[i].getAttribute('data-textcontent'));
  if (aTags[i].getAttribute('data-textcontent') == searchText){ 
    aTags[i].setAttribute('data-value','123456789');  
    found = aTags[i].getAttribute('data-value');
    break;
  }
}

console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery you can access the data attributes directly, but you must cycle through them as there may be more than one:

```
$.each($('input[data-value='']'),function(){
   $(this).data('value','12345678'); 
});
```

or, if the input field is just one, use an id:

```
<input type='password' id="pwd" data-value="" />
```

and

```
$('#pwd').data('value','12346578');
```